# Group By DATE (Second) in Sql Plus

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table where I want to group by the records on the basis of seconds ? Please suggest what I can do ?

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: `group by extract(second from record)`

Comment: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9532073600346112319

Comment: If the column is a date (rather than a timestamp), as your question title suggests - then what's group with just grouping by that column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out [AskTOM](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9532073600346112319).

```
CAST(<my_ts> AS TIMESTAMP(0))
```

should work (as @user3863616 suggested)

Comment: Don't know why, but seconds are not a supported format :-)

Comment: because seconds are not supported format for trunc :)

Comment: Trunc only accepts dates, not timestamps - though they would be implicitly converted of course - and doesn't support any format model elements that only relate to timestamps. [The valid formats are in the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions271.htm#SQLRF52058). Truncatng a date to seconds would leave you with the same value, so would be pointless,..